# How to point site hosted on iis to domain name?

Tags: iis

I just published my site on IIS and I can access it by going to http://localhost:3302/admin/index  on my server. I would like other computers on my network to access the site at http://mikesdemo.com , how do I point my site to this domain through IIS ?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

Comment: You can configure the IP mapping of mikesdemo.com in your HOST file, then use the url to rewrite `http://localhost:3302/admin/index` to `http://mikesdemo.com`. about how to use the url rewrite you can refer to this link: [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)